# Apply script on another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing, text-editor

I have a text editor and i want when you print print to see results with no date,link or title thats why i use this script to have 0 margin and portrait

```js
var cssPagedMedia = (function () {
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    return function (rule) {
        style.innerHTML = rule;
    };
}());

cssPagedMedia.margin = function (margin) {
    cssPagedMedia('@page {margin: ' + margin + '}');
};

cssPagedMedia.margin('0');

cssPagedMedia.size = function (size) {
    cssPagedMedia('@page {size: ' + size + '}');
};

var cssPagedMedia = (function () {
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    return function (rule) {
        style.innerHTML = rule;
    };
}());

cssPagedMedia.size = function (size) {
    cssPagedMedia('@page {size: ' + size + '}');
};

cssPagedMedia.size('portrait');
```

But this script work only on the main page if you tried to print it but not text in text-editor and you can see [example](https://unripened-amperes.000webhostapp.com/)

and i want to apply previous script on the text editor's javascript and this the whole javascript of the text-editor

```js
var oDoc, sDefTxt;

function initDoc() {
  oDoc = document.getElementById("textBox");
  sDefTxt = oDoc.innerHTML;
  if (document.compForm.switchMode.checked) { setDocMode(true); }
}

function formatDoc(sCmd, sValue) {
  if (validateMode()) { document.execCommand(sCmd, false, sValue); oDoc.focus(); }
}

function validateMode() {
  if (!document.compForm.switchMode.checked) { return true ; }
  alert("Uncheck \"Show HTML\".");
  oDoc.focus();
  return false;
}

function setDocMode(bToSource) {
  var oContent;
  if (bToSource) {
    oContent = document.createTextNode(oDoc.innerHTML);
    oDoc.innerHTML = "";
    var oPre = document.createElement("pre");
    oDoc.contentEditable = false;
    oPre.id = "sourceText";
    oPre.contentEditable = true;
    oPre.appendChild(oContent);
    oDoc.appendChild(oPre);
    document.execCommand("defaultParagraphSeparator", false, "div");
  } else {
    if (document.all) {
      oDoc.innerHTML = oDoc.innerText;
    } else {
      oContent = document.createRange();
      oContent.selectNodeContents(oDoc.firstChild);
      oDoc.innerHTML = oContent.toString();
    }
    oDoc.contentEditable = true;
  }
  oDoc.focus();
}

function printDoc() {
  if (!validateMode()) { return; }
  var oPrntWin = window.open("","inlineFrameExample","width=450,height=470,left=400,top=100,menubar=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes");
  oPrntWin.document.open();
  oPrntWin.document.write("<!doctype html><html><head><title><\/title><\/head><body onload=\"print();\">"+ "<div dir='rtl'>" + oDoc.innerHTML + "<\/body><\/html>");
  oPrntWin.document.close();
}
/*page margin*/
var cssPagedMedia = (function () {
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    return function (rule) {
        style.innerHTML = rule;
    };
}());

cssPagedMedia.margin = function (margin) {
    cssPagedMedia('@page {margin: ' + margin + '}');
};

cssPagedMedia.margin('0');
/*page size*/
cssPagedMedia.size = function (size) {
    cssPagedMedia('@page {size: ' + size + '}');
};

var cssPagedMedia = (function () {
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    return function (rule) {
        style.innerHTML = rule;
    };
}());

cssPagedMedia.size = function (size) {
    cssPagedMedia('@page {size: ' + size + '}');
};

cssPagedMedia.size('portrait');
```

So how can i make printing for text-editor show 0 margin and protrait no matter what are the default printing settings in your browser ?